# How does np.interp works?

Tags: python, interpolation

[data view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFNVl.png)
I am working with data that is made by np.interp using this code:

```
np.array([np.interp(raw_timestamps[:36000], output_timestamps, output[:, i]) for i in range(output.shape[1])]).transpose()
```

the interpolated data has a size of 36000 (black points) and this data is made by interpolating a larger data which has 155585 points(pink points). when I was checking the accuracy of the data I noticed that some of the interpolated points don't seem like the linear average of their previous and after points. like the picture black points are out of pink point linear traces. I search a lot but I could not find out why it happens.

Comment: Are `output_timestamps` in strictly increasing order?  `np.interp()` requires that in order to give meaningful results, but doesn't do anything to verify it.

Comment: yes, they increase. output_timestamps  start from 0 and increase to 1000 in each step.